Comparison theorem for SDEs driven by a continuous martingale
Consider the well-known comparison theorem for SDEs, versions of which appear in several textbooks, e.g., Karatzas and Shreve, Proposition 5.2.18, or Revuz and Yor, Theorem IX.3.7.
The result states that if we have two SDEs
$$ dX = b_1(X,t)dt+\sigma(X,t)dW $$
and
$$ dX = b_2(X,t)dt+\sigma(X,t)dW $$
with $b_1\leq b_2$, and $X_1,X_2$ are solutions (respectively), satisfying $X_1(0)\leq X_2(0)$ a.s., then $X_1(t)\leq X_2(t)$ for all $t\geq0$, a.s. There are hypotheses about $b_1$, $b_2$, and $\sigma$.
My question is: Is there a similar result if the SDEs are driven by a continuous martingale (not necessarily BM)? If there is such a result, what conditions must that martingale satisfy? And are the hypotheses about $b_1$, $b_2$, and $\sigma$ different?

Protter's book has a version with continuous semimartingales

Thank you! That's a great reference. Unfortunately, it deals with the strict comparison version, with Lipschitz requirements on $\sigma$, while I need something like the non-strict version, with a bit weaker requirements on $\sigma$. Still useful, though!
